# For a camera activity, result code is -1 in onActivityResult(). How to proceed debugging?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

None of the submissions here deal with negative result code. I know it means that the task failed, but I have no idea how or why it failed. The app opens the camera and I'm able to take a picture.

```
btnN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                captureImage(v);
            }
        });
```

The function definitions are as given below.

```
public void captureImage(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File imageFile = null;
            try {
                imageFile = getImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (imageFile != null) {
                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.testingproject.fileprovider", imageFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
            }
            System.out.println("imageFile length:" + imageFile.length());

        }

    }
```

In the above function, I've even tried sending request code as 2. Same functionality, I'm able to click a picture, but same issue.

```
    public File getImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmsss").format(new Date());
        String imageName = "jpg_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("currImPath: " + currentImagePath);
        return imageFile;
    }
```

The much needed `onActivityResult()` code is below

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        try {
            System.out.println("reqCode: "+requestCode+" resCode: "+resultCode);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0: {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        File file = new File(currentImagePath);
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                        //...Do your stuffs
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bitmap NOT null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"BitmapNull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }




                    break;
                }
                default: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"result code not okay",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); break;
            }

        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The sysout in log is below

```
2020-05-01 13:52:24.644 10014-10014/com.example.testingproject I/System.out: reqCode: 1 resCode: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

-1 is equal to RESULT_OK. It means the task completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

When you look into the code. `-1` is actully status code for `RESULT_OK`

```
 public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
```

Now you've set `requestCode` as 1 in this line

```
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
```

So in your `OnActivityResult` which shows

```
reqCode: 1 resCode: -1
```

is Correct.